# IOS custom button

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, custom-controls

I need a custom button like Instragram has in profile tab (the buttons that shows the number of photos and followers) but i don't know how to start to implement it. 
Do i need to subclass UIButton or is there other way easier?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the easiest approach would be to create a UIButtom with the type`UIButtonTypeCustom` and add a subview to it with imageviews and labels as subviews to create the UI. Composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing UIButton seems to me to be the obvious solution. I agree that subclassing UIViewController makes no sense. You don't use UIViewController objects to manipulate individual subviews within a view hierarchy controlled by another UIViewController object.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this, personally I would subclass UIViewController. Then you can edit its .xib in interface builder to make it look however you want and set different values programmatically. Then to detect a tap on the button you can just use the touchesBegan and touchesEnded (I'm pretty sure those aren't complete method names, check in the docs for more info on them) methods. If you want you could also set up a UITapGestureRecognizer for the view instead.

Comment: Why do I have to subclass UIViewController if I want to have a subclass of a view (what UIButton is)? Why do I have to deal with the touches… methods, when UIButtons are meant to use UIController's `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` and similar methods?

Comment: You don't. That's just the way I would do it; I prefer to have a separate controller for something like that. If you wanted to subclass UIButton and override drawRect: then go right ahead. Or I'm pretty sure you could create a .xib and load your subclass with that. I just don't have a ton of experience doing it that way.

Comment: Apple is offering the custom style to do customization. Just see my answer.